# "Not in" in entity frame work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have student class

```
Class Student
{
String Name;
Int id;
}
```

I have list of unwanted students

```
List <string> unwantedNames =new List <string>{"xxx","bbbb"};
```

I have to get a list of DbSet (entity frame work) of all Students
whose name are not in  unwantedNames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var students = _context.Set<Student>().Where(x => !unwantedNames.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
```

Rather than retrieve students that are contained, it retrieves all students who are NOT contained in your exclusion list.